# window.open in java bean

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

i need to create a pop up window from my java. Can anyone give me some samples for creating window.open popup from java bean? I have a list of records created from java. in that list i have a column called ID with anchor link. When clicking on that link it should open the popup and retrieve the details.

```
No   Name   Amount
1    xxx     15
2    uuu     20
3    uku     23
4    iko     09
```

Comment: Which web framework are you using?

Comment: Independent of the framework, you should seriously reconsider your system's architecture if you "need" to open a window from inside the Java Bean.

Comment: well you cant. Struts is run server side and send HTML to your client so you will have to make it so that your javabean renders the correct HTML/Javascript for your client to open the window you need.

Comment: oh oh ....ok i ll check with my leads and try to change the request,...thanks buddy... realy helped to save my time lot...

Comment: friend is it possible to show the details in tooltip on mouseover?

Comment: Yes, you could show a tooltip. However, you'd have to render the details for every tooltip when you render the page. This might be a lot of data, depending on what would be contained and how many entries you'd have. As for the popup (which is not possible from the Java bean but using JavaScript) look at Kiran's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you know some  javaScript for this .

On click of a Link call a function this way

```
<script>
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
var targetWin = window.open ("http:localhost:8080/MyServlet?name="+kiran"")
} 
</script>
```

**Process your request with Servlet , get the Data and show it on that page.** 

In case you use Struts, replace servlet with a Action class .